# Fixed height of table row in html

Tags: html, css, tablerow

I have a table hosted in a div. Neither the table nor the hosting div has a height specified.
After the table header row, each subsequent row looks like this:

```
<tr class="movie-info-row">
    <td>
        <div class="movie-cover">
            <img class="movie-image" src="" />
            <a class="movie-link" href="" target="_blank">IMDb</a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan=5>
        <div class="movie-details">
            <p class="movie-file"></p>
            <div class="movie-div-left">
                <p class="movie-category"></p>
                <p class="movie-director"></p>
                <p class="movie-insertdate"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="movie-description-container">
                <p class="movie-description"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want each table row (except for the header) to have the same fixed height but I just can't get it to work after hours of trying all kinds of approaches (and of course searching on stackoverflow and elsewhere).

My css (in less syntax) looks like this:

```
.movie-info-row {
    height: 240px;

    p {
        margin-top: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
    }

    td {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}

.movie-cover {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 130px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.movie-details {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.movie-file {
    font-size:larger;
}

.movie-div-left {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}

.movie-description-container {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.movie-description {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

As you can see I have fixed the height of the row to 240px and for good measure have each `td` height set to 100% with overflow hidden.
The trouble maker is the description text, which can be quite long and it messes with the table row height. As you can see I have set overflow to hidden in many places (which is probably overkill).
Note: This is not browser specific. I am not even using IE. I am testing it with firefox and chrome (both latest versions).

I am really at a loss. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ETA:
Here's a picture of a table row as it looks now: [SampleRow](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27561271/SampleRow.png)

As you can see the description text takes the row height with it. I want it limited to a fixed height - basically the hight of the title image. And yes, I want all the information (with more to come) in there. So that is non-negotiable.

Comment: It seems to be working fine with jsfiddle. Try simplifying your code when you are at situations like this. Try a simple 1x2 table with adjusted height and then add in your contents.

Comment: Are you sure you want colspan/rowspan?

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of your HTML all of your data will go into one table cell is this how you want it?

Why not structure it like using individual  tags for the headers with a colspan of what ever and then do a new  for each row you need along with its data like this?

```
<tr>
 <th colspan=2>Header</th>
</tr> 
<tr>
 <td>cell 1 data</td>
 <td>cell 2 data</td>
<tr>
```

Then you can do this in the css, which would give you this same fixed height for all the rows:

```
tr {
 height: 240px;
}
```

That way you can just use the table headers to describe each column and use a lot less code to make it work properly.  Or from what I understand you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, that's how I want it. Please see my updated OP. I have included a link to a screen shot. I am almost there, except for some styling (text, colors) and the table row height issue.

Answer (score 1):

Too many hiddens and floats and whatnot.  Simplify and conquer.  Also you have nested selectors inside of another selector (`p{} and td{}`)

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nbbd/)

### CSS:

```
.movie-info-row {
    height: 240px;
}
p {
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}
div, p {
    display: table-cell;
}
.movie-cover {
    width: 130px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.movie-details {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.movie-file {
    font-size:larger;
}
.movie-div-left {
    width: 35%;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
.movie-description-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 55%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.movie-description {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Well since I don't have a LESS parser I guess that makes sense then lol

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. However, adding a long description text shows exactly the problem I am having. See also the screen shot link in my updated OP.